# What is a non-trivial destructor in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor

I was reading [this](ftp://ftp.cs.uregina.ca/pub/class/210/C++FAQ/virtual-functions.html#20.4) which mentions destructors being trivial and non-trivial.

> A class has a non-trivial destructor if it either has an explicitly
>   defined destructor, or if it has a member object or a base class that
>   has a non-trivial destructor.

In example, I have a class,

```
class C {
    public:
     ~C(); // not explicitly declared.
};
```

If `C::~C()` is implicitly defined does it make a trival dtor?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are getting your words mixed up. Your example does indeed *declare* an explicit destructor. You just forget to *define* it, too, so you'll get a linker error.

The rule is very straight-forward: Does your class have an explicit destructor? If yes, you're non-trivial. If no, check each non-static member object; if any of *them* are non-trivial, then you're non-trivial.

Comment: and as a side note:   `C::~C() { }` is still a non-trivial destructor.  Even if you do nothing, *you* are doing nothing.  Trivial destructors/constructors are always created by the compiler for you.

Comment: @CortAmmon: To be more precise, it needs to be *implicitly-defined*. It's OK to be user-declared, if it is also *defaulted* (which must happen at the first declaration).

Comment: Interesting I had to look that one up.   I knew about = delete, but not = default

Comment: @KerrekSB `check each non-static member object; if any of them are non-trivial` I don't get this, what is meant by non trivial non static member ?

Comment: @KerrekSB __1.__ what is meant by `non static non trivial object` ? __2.__  can you mention when destructor will be `trivial`  type ?

Answer (score 4):

So you mean, the entire declaration of `C` is this:

```
class C { };
```

?

Then, yes: Since `C` has no member objects and no base classes, it therefore has no member objects with non-trivial destructors and no base classes with non-trivial destructors, so its implicitly-defined destructor is a trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general it refers to a **destructor that actually does something** such as:

- Release memory
- Close a connection to database
- Or take care of any resource that needs to be released

In this case the destructor does nothing.  According to the description, technically it may be 'non-trivial' because it defines a constructor, but it matters not, since it does nothing anyway.

Comment: It's more a destructor that *may* do something. If the destructor is defined in a different translation unit from code that uses the class (`C.cpp` vs. `main.cpp` or whatnot), then when the compiler is compiling `main.cpp`, it has to assume that it needs to call `C`'s destructor whenever an automatically-stored instance of `C` goes out of scope, because it has no way of knowing that that destructor doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: "_In this case the destructor does nothing._" How do you know? The definition of the dtor is not given.

Comment: *trivial destructor* is a technical term used by the standard and OP's destructir is non-trivial according to the definition of that term.