# Rule "A user-defined but do-nothing destructor is also a non-trivial destructor" is too strict?

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
public:
    ~Base() {}
private:
    int val;
};

Base base; // a global variable
```

Look, the destructor does nothing, just same as the default destructor provided by c++ complier. But the destructor is still also a non-trivial destructor accroding to the post [What is a non-trivial destructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190879/what-is-a-non-trivial-destructor-in-c)

I know, each RULE from the standard must be strict.

But, by the upper codes I pasted, the user-defined destructor does nothing really! Why it is also non-trivial? I don't understand....

Is there any magic I don't konw?

Comment: "There is no user-defined destructor" is easier to say than "there is no non-empty user-defined destructor". Easier to implement too (for compilers and libraries using meta-programming). Does that rule stop you from doing anything in particular?

Comment: @Nelfeal No, just a doubt while I was reading the upper [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190879/what-is-a-non-trivial-destructor-in-c) I pasted it on ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the rule absolutely prohibit a definition gives a **meaning** to providing an empty one: it specifies that its instances must not be forgotten in an array that provides their storage.  What the destructor *does*, if anything, can be considered an **implementation detail** that might change in future versions.  It also avoids a change in meaning based on whether the “empty” destructor is *defined* in the class definition; if it isn’t, it can even be binary-compatible to change it to do something.